# PHP - Get number of items in array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, pdo

OK, so I got a while loop, in which I loop through different users:

```
$before = $data['autorenew_before'];
$refs=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_by=:userby AND expire <= unix_timestamp(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL :before day)");
    #$refs->bindParam(":userby",$data['username']);
    $refs->bindParam(":userby",$userdata['username']);
    $refs->bindParam(":before",$before);
    $refs->execute();
```

I then loop through the above query:

```
while($refsData=$refs->fetch()){
$ids = "".$refsData['id'].",";
$explode = explode(",",$ids);
$outcome = _paying(number_format(getPriceList($data['rented_referrals']),2), 30, $data['username'], $explode);


}
```

This is the `_paying` function:

```
function _paying($ceny, $dni, $username, $referrals_array){
  //$ceny = 0.20

  //Count referrals_array doesn't return anything. 
  $koszyk = $ceny * count($referrals_array);

   return $koszyk;


}
```

The above function doesn't work, as the `count($referrals_array)` is not working.

**Edit - 1**:

`print_r($explode);` gives me:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 40231
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40232
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40233
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40234
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 40235
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 55847
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 55848
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90322
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90323
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90324
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90325
    [1] => 
)
Array
(
    [0] => 90326
    [1] => 
)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the content of `$explode` yet?
Try a `print_r($explode);` before calling `_paying()` to make sure, there is data.

Comment: please see my updated question. I have pasted the content of print_r($explode);